# How to get a rule for, e.g., (x + y) to apply to (-x - y), etc.?

Tags: replacement, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

For example, the substitution `(x + y) -> s` fails here:

```
In[1]:= (-x - y) /. (x + y) -> s

Out[1]= -x - y
```

Of course, I could try applying the rule `(-x - y) -> -s`, but this strategy becomes unwieldy in more complicated cases.  At the very least it would require duplicating a lot of rules.  For example, if the expression to be transformed were something like

```
(x + y)^2 + 2 (-x - y)
```

...then I'd need to use something like

```
{(x + y) -> s, (-x - y) -> -s}
```

Is there a better way to transform the above expression to `s^2 - 2 s`?

Comment: Not sure if you find it better: `expr /. x -> (s - y)`

Comment: Use `FullForm[x + y]` and `FullForm[-x - y]` to see how those two expressions are different (or `TreeForm` if you are feeling daring).  `ReplaceAll` is a dumb function that is not going to transform your expression for you.  It may not be friendly, but it is reliable.  In general, as Kuba has suggested, it's better to replace atomic elements.

Comment: It sounds like the transformation you are trying to do it more mathematica than formal.  In these cases you can consider `Eliminate` or `GroebnerBasis` too, [e.g. like here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28864/12)  It depends on the situation if they work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods to create patterns that match; the first uses a default value, while the second uses an explicit [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) expression.

```
p1 = x (s_: - 1) + y (ss_: - 1);
p2 = (x | -x) + (y | -y);

expr = {x + y, x - y, -x + y, -y - x};

MatchQ[#, p1] & /@ expr
MatchQ[#, p2] & /@ expr
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True}
>
> {True, True, True, True}
> ```

If you specify how you want to handle the sign in all cases I can recommend something for the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
poly=(x + y)^2 + 2 (-x - y)//Simplify;
poly//.{(x + y)-> s}

(*(-2 + s) s*)
```